# obtener los datos de un array en angularjs

Tags: angularjs, array

Tengo el siguiente `array`:

```
vm.model= {"left":false,"middle":true,"right":false}
```

Del cual quiero obtener el valor de cada ítem del arreglo y guardarlo en la *Base de Datos*, pero no sé cómo obtener por ejemplo `left` y su valor `false` en `angularjs`.

En síntesis necesito obtener la primera posición del arreglo en otros lenguajes seria `vm.model[0]` primer posición.

Agradecería una respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Realmente lo que estas haciendo es crear un objeto por eso no te funciona con `vm.model[0]` para acceder a alguno de los elementos sería con la notación con punto de los objetos `vm.model.left` con esto tendrás acceso al primer valor.

Para utilizar un array sería su creación con corchetes `vm.model = [true,false,true]` de este modo puedes acceder con `vm.model[1]` pero entiendo que lo que quieres es crear un array asociativo para eso deberías hacerlo así:

```
vm.model = new Array();
vm.model['uno'] = 1;
vm.model['dos] = 2;
```

Y podrías acceder como quieres `vm.model['uno']` o `vm.model[0]`

Pero bueno personalmente cuando quiero usar lo de arrays asociativos utilizo la notación objeto que indicas tú que es la que encuentro más práctica pero eso tú sabrás mejor que nadie cual de las 3 maneras es la que necesitas.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa que yo de este modelo Model: {"left":true,"middle":true,"right":true}
quiero obtener el siguiente resultado Results: ["left","middle","right"]; es un checkbox-group de angularjs el cual estoy utilizando para obtener valores de la base datos pero mi problema va al querer guardar los valores que hay en el results.
variables utilizadas
 vm.checkModel = {};
 vm.checkResults = [];

de verdad quisieran que me ayudaran soy nueva en angularjs y javascritp y no entiendo muchos sobre el tema. Agradeceria una respuesta.

Comment: Entonces como sería? si entiendo bien en Results guardarías las keys de aquellos que son true? es decir si tenemos Model: {left:true,middle:false,right:false} los valores obtenidos en results serían Results: ["left"]. Seria así?